# How to use jquery variable as global

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(function($){

     $(window).resize(function(e) {
            $('.video1').each(function() {
                slwidth = $(this).width();
             });
     });
    var sliderLength=parseInt(jQuery('.video_wrpr .video1').length);
    $('.video_wrpr').width((sliderLength*slwidth));
```

I want to use **slwidth** as global variable. I used window.slwidth but its not working.
Actually am trying to get width of div on resize and onload.

Comment: what exactly do you want it to do....your code over writes it each pass of the `each` loop, will only ever be the value of last video. And since you haven't used `var` it is already global

Answer (score 0):

make it global

```
 jQuery(function($){
     var slwidth =''; 
     $(window).resize(function(e) {
         $('.video1').each(function() {
             slwidth = $(this).width();
         });
     });
 var sliderLength=parseInt(jQuery('.video_wrpr .video1').length);
 $('.video_wrpr').width((sliderLength*slwidth));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The you need to set the width of the wrapper also in the resize() handler.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $videos = $('.video_wrpr .video1');
    $(window).resize(function (e) {
        var slwidth = $videos.width();
        var sliderLength = $('.video_wrpr .video1').length;
        $('.video_wrpr').width((sliderLength * slwidth));
    }).resize();
});
```